# Slickgrid filter not working in IE

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I just finished my first SlickGrid implementation at [www.werelate.org/wiki/Special:ListPages/Jdfoote1](http://www.werelate.org/wiki/Special%3aListPages/Jdfoote1).

Unfortunately, I've been getting reports back that the filter doesn't work on IE. I'm wondering if there are known issues with SlickGrid filtering on IE. Here's the offending code:

```
// Define search filter (currently searches name, birth place, and death place)
function myFilter(item) {
var searchWords = getWords(searchString);
var searchFields = ["name","birthPlace","deathPlace", "birthDate", "deathDate"];
if (searchWords){
    // Go through each of the words in the search string
    for (j in searchWords){
        var itemFound = false;
        searchWord = searchWords[j].toUpperCase();
        // Make sure that the word is in at least one of the search fields.
        for (i in searchFields){
            if (item[searchFields[i]].toUpperCase().indexOf(searchWord) != -1){
                itemFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (itemFound === false){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
    return true;
}

// Get all of the words in a search string
function getWords(wordString){
    pattern = /[^, ]+/g;
    wordArray = wordString.match(pattern);
    return wordArray;
}
```

Very many thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all in Chrome.  No JS errors get reported.

Comment: Sorry - this is just one very small portion of the code.

Answer (score 0):

So, I learned that the problem was my for loop. I guess IE requires loops in the format

```
for (variable=startvalue;variable<=endvalue;variable=variable+increment)
```

So, my

```
for (j in searchWords)
```

broke things because you can't loop through an array like that. Oops. :)